# Generating a precisely timed expanding circle in PsychoPy

Tags: python-3.x, psychopy

Using PsychoPy, I am trying to write a simple script that generates an expanding circle that:

1) Expands from 2 to 20 degrees of visual angle over 250 ms.

2) Holds at 20 degrees for another 250 ms.

3) Repeats n number of times with 500 ms interstimulus interval (blank, grey screen) between repetitions.

The Python code I have so far:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event

# Define the window/background.
win=visual.Window([800,600],monitor="testMonitor",units="deg")

# Setting up some variables: I'm not sure how best to use them:

# Number of epochs (repetitions)
EPOCH=15

# Stimulus initial size
INIT_RAD=2

# Stimulus end size
END_RAD=10

# Duration of expansion
EXPANSION_MS=250

# Hold duration
HOLD_TIME_MS=250

# ISI duration
ISI_MS=500

# Time-to-frame conversion assuming a 60Hz FR and RR
FRAMES=int((60*EXPANSION_MS)/1000)
print(FRAMES)

# Define the stimulus
circle=visual.Circle(win,radius=1,edges=1000,fillColor='black',lineColor='black')

for e in range(EPOCH):
    for f in range(FRAMES):
        while circle.radius<10:
            circle.radius+=1
            circle.draw()
            win.flip()
#        for f in range(FRAMES): # Doesn't seem to work - takes much longer than 250 ms.
#            circle.radius=20
#            circle.draw()
#            win.flip()
    print(circle.radius)
    circle.radius=1

# Get keys to quit.
if len(event.getKeys())>0:
    event.clearEvents()
    win.close()
```

I'm still new to Python and if anyone can offer some suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You haven't really asked a specific question? And the resolution will be specific to your particular code, rather than being of general interest. So as this might require some hand-holding and discussion rather than the single question/answer format here at SO, so I'd suggest taking it to the dedicated forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org instead.

Comment: OK, thanks, Michael. I will revise and resubmit the question there.

Comment: The good news is that you've done most of the work: it is just some very simple algebra to get the result you need, along with using the API fully to specify the units of stimuli.